# Remove license message in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to disable the license notification for a plugin a bought a few months ago. Now my license for updates is not longer valid but I don't want to receive any updates anymore because I've changed a lot in the plugin. This is the message:

[image]

I've tried to remove it this way:

```
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['cred-frontend-editor/plugin.php'] );

    return $value;
}
```

But when I refresh the page the notification is still there. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the plugin. But the steps I would take.

1. Search to plugin codebase for variations of `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'callback_notice function')`
2. Then try to use [remove_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) to de-hook that notice.
   Keep in mind `remove_action` has to run *after* the `add_action`, So if that add_action is done inside an `add_action('admin_init', ...,10)` (prio 10) you should run the remove action in an `add_action('admin_init', ...,11)`
   Yes this part is confusing.

Good luck

**Edit**

Given the code you provided the remove should be:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', array( WP_Installer::instance(), 'setup_plugins_page_notices' ) );
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', array( WP_Installer::instance(), 'setup_plugins_renew_warnings' ), 10 );
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', array( WP_Installer::instance(), 'queue_plugins_renew_warnings' ), 20 );
}, 100);
```

The add_actions are run in the `init` function. the `init` function is hooked in the , well the  `init` hook, at default priority (10)

So we run the removes *after* that in the `init` hook at prio 11.

Probably you don't need to remove the `setup_plugins_page_notices` hook.

Comment: Hey JanW, thanks for your answer. I'll try to find it and let u know if it works.

Comment: I've found the place. This adds the notice: 

add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'setup_plugins_page_notices' ) );

I've tried to add this to my functions.php:

remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'setup_plugins_page_notices', 9999 );

But this has no effect.

Comment: Oh yeah.. `$this` makes this more difficult. The class that this is in. Can you get that specific instance?

Comment: I'm not sure. Here can you find the class where it get's set: https://codeshare.io/adDlDK

Comment: It works. This is so cool! Thanks a lot and have a great weekend.